# Project does not build from Jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins, nmake

When I try to build a project in Windows, I run one script - start.py, and project IS built successfully.

When I try to build using Jenkins (in win and with the same user), the build comes to 60% and fails with errors:

> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
>       Stop.
>       Failed to run make: ['nmake', 'install']

What can I do to fix this?

UPD: Error occurs when more than one build runs at the same time. 
Fix: run builds in queue

Comment: You question is most likely "How can I debug this".  Your project and build have way to many unique details for someone to just come up with an answer unless this happens to be a widely known bug in Jenkins, but then you would have found a solution when you searched...

Comment: I can't debug it because I have no information about inner structure of build script, it was a black box. I think, but I am not sure, if project is built on Win without Jenkins, then script uses CMake instead of NMake.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are one critical part that differs when triggering a build from jenkins. Make sure you are not missing any path in $PATH that may prevent you build. You can try printing path variable by adding a execute shell command at build operations